# Error with com reference in WCF with dll done in VFP

Tags: c#, http, wcf, visual-foxpro

I have a dll done in VFP that I need to use to be able to perform some processes in the DBF, I add the normal reference, I can use the class in my WCF project.

```
public API _api;
var _api = new API();
_api.version();
```

When I make the first call it works fine, but when I make the other call to the service the following error appears:

```
Failed to create an instance of the COM component with CLSID {FD80E726-1A66- 
4823-9D96-D6F00C8B2665} from IClassFactory due to the following error: 
80004005 Unspecified error (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).
```

I do not know what could happen when the class returns.

```
public Document PostDocument(Document document)
{
   var _api = new API();
   _api.importar();
   return document;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: there the error is specified, there is also the method that I use to call the dll, that as I mention it works in the first call of the service, to the second one it is not possible to instantiate the dll object